# subprocess always running with low integrity level?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, permissions, uac

I'm working on a patcher for a unity game in c#. Because the game is built with il2cpp which doesn't support `system.diagnostics.Process` I am forced to launch the patcher via the windows api.
My problem is that the patcher always runs with low integrity level which only allows access to the `appdata/locallow` directory.
I doublechecked that all parts of the unity game are always running with medium level but the subprocess is always demoted to low.
I tried the CreateProcessA and the ShellExecuteA API calls both with every reasonable combination of valid arguments I could come up with. The result stayed the same. Despite the parent clearly having medium integrity the child always ends up with a low integrity level.
I even tried some [old code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/23090/Creating-a-Process-with-Medium) that uses a security token from another process to gain medium integrity. It succeeds in launching my program but again only with low integrity.
I get medium Integrity if I launch the program via click or from vs itself but when calling it from a cmd I get the same low integrity while the cmd/PowerShell is running on medium.
Setting the integrity level with icacls doesn't make a difference either.

The patcher is just a simple .net 4 windows forms application (to prevent issues with old wine etc.) that works with file deltas.

I am clearly missing something here. Does anyone know why this is? It's kind of hard to find anything because all results either talk about uac admin elevation or about how to lower one's integrity.

I tried to read into integrity and permissions on msdn in general but that's a bottomless pit and is frankly just too complex for me.

I could just always require uac admin elevation myself which works fine btw. but that's not how this is supposed to work.

Can it really be that hard to just run a program that inherits the parent's integrity level? From what I found so far that should be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your file into LocalLow? Windows starts applications inside this folder with Low integrity IIRC.